# program spinning on pthread lock

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, critical-section

After banging my head against a wall for a few hours during this exercise, I am stuck at that wall.
First off, this is a program designed to find and print all prime numbers between 1 and `ceiling`, where ceiling is some user input. The design is to implement POSIX threads.

In my program, it runs successfully until on one of the later iterations in the thread's method. When it gets to that later iteration, it steps to the line `pthread_mutex_lock(lock);` and spins, forcing me to kill it with Ctrl+z. The 2 input's I've been using are `1` for the number of threads and `10` for the ceiling. This flaw is reproducible as it happens every time I've tried it. note: although this code should be able to implement multiple threads, I'd like to get it working correctly with 1 child thread before adding more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int* numbermarker = NULL;
int* buffer = NULL;
int* checked = NULL;
int pullposition = 0;
int placeposition = 0;
pthread_mutex_t* lock;
int ceiling;

/*This method places one of the primes in the buffer. It 
offers a safe way to manage where the next value will be placed*/
void placevalue(int value){
    buffer[placeposition] = value;
    placeposition++;
}


void* threadmethod(){   
    int i;
    int k;
    int l;
    while(1){   
        printf("pull %d   number %d \n",pullposition, buffer[pullposition]);
        pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
        printf("FLAG\n");
        l = buffer[pullposition];
        pullposition++;
        printf("pullTWO %d   number %d \n",pullposition, buffer[pullposition-1]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);
        for(k=l+1;k<=ceiling;k++){
            if(k%l){
                if(k%2){
                    checked[k]=1;
                    placevalue(k);
                }
            }
            else{
                numbermarker[k-1] = 1;
            }
        }
        int sum=0;
        for(i=0; i<ceiling; i++){
            if(numbermarker[i]){
                checked[i] = numbermarker[i];
            }
            printf("checked|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|\n",
checked[0], checked[1], checked[2], checked[3], checked[4], checked[5], checked[6], checked[7], checked[8], checked[9]); 
            sum += checked[i];
            printf("sum %d    ceiling %d\n",sum,ceiling);
        }
        printf("number |%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|\n",
numbermarker[0],    numbermarker[1],    numbermarker[2],    numbermarker[3],    numbermarker[4],    numbermarker[5],    numbermarker[6],    numbermarker[7],    numbermarker[8],    numbermarker[9]);
        if(sum == ceiling){
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int numthreads;
    int i;

    printf("Enter number of threads: \n");
    scanf("%d", &numthreads);

    printf("Enter the highest value to check \n");
    scanf("%d", &ceiling);

    /*  This will hold 1's and 0's.
            1 = number has been checked or is
                    confirmed not to be a prime
            0 = number is a possible prime

            The idea behind these values is that the next
            prime can always be identified by the 0 with
            the lowest index
    */

    numbermarker = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(ceiling));
    checked = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(ceiling));

    /*This will hold the primes as they are found*/
    buffer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(ceiling));

    /*allocate space for the lock*/
    lock = (pthread_mutex_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    pthread_mutex_init(lock,NULL);

    for(i=0; i<ceiling; i++){
        if(i<1){
            numbermarker[i] = 1;
        }
        else{
            numbermarker[i] = 0;
        }
        checked[i]=0;
        buffer[i]=0;
        printf("%d \n",numbermarker[i]);
    }
    checked[0]=1;
    placevalue(2);
    printf("checked|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|%d|\n", checked[0], checked[1], checked[2], checked[3], checked[4], checked[5], checked[6], checked[7], checked[8], checked[9]);

    pthread_t **tid = (pthread_t **) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t *) * numthreads);

    for(i=0;i<numthreads;i++){
        tid[i] = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
    }

    for(i=0;i<numthreads;i++){
        if(pthread_create(tid[i],
                                            NULL,
                                            threadmethod,
                                            NULL)){
            printf("Could not create thread \n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }       

    for(i=0;i<numthreads;i++){
        if(pthread_join(*tid[i], NULL)){
            printf("Error Joining with thread \n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        free(tid[i]);
    }

    free(tid);
    for(i=0;i<ceiling;i++){
        if(numbermarker[i] == 0){
            printf("%d sdfsddd \n", numbermarker[i]);
            printf("%d \n", i+1);
        }
    }

    free(buffer);
    free(numbermarker);
    buffer=NULL;
    numbermarker=NULL;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually debugging it a bit and telling us where the stall is - can't say how many times people ask without trying themselves first.

Comment: While maybe not the solution, I do see a lot of random array accessing going on.  Any chance you are reading off the end of a buffer and trashing the mutex's memory location thus causing the stall?  The thread code itself looks benign enough so I'm looking into other avenues.

Comment: I would say that's a possibility but since it's being allocated in the heap, i don't think it's likely that it would overwrite the lock every time I run the program.

Comment: You're not checking for `l == 0` in the expression `k%l`. When I run it, the program crashes due to a divide by zero. Is it possible your thread dies without crashing the program, causing it to never release the lock?

Comment: You have bug in last loop in main(), by mistake added `;` `if(numbermarker[i] == 0);` Check your code. I am removing my answer because this can't be reason for bug you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your code and in

```
void placevalue(int value)
{
buffer[placeposition] = value;
placeposition++;
}
```

`placeposition` goes beyond the size of `buffer`. This results in undefined behaviour, a very plausible outcome of which is the trashing of the mutex (which is `malloc()`ed right after `buffer`).

On top of that, there's a race condition is `placevalue()`. However, if you're using a single worker thread, you are not (yet) running into it.

Comment: This is likely due to the  `for(k=l+1;k<=ceiling;k++)` loop, which can make `k` be one past the sizes of the dynamically allocated buffer and checked arrays.

Comment: NPE's answer is right, but that is not the reason placeposition goes beyond the size of the buffer.  The code is redundantly finding primes, so it ends up writing 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9 | then going past the buffer and writing 7, 9, 9, and this final 9 (on my system, the behavior is undefined) ends up writing into the lock and causing it to believe there are 9 lock "users".